# Asp.Net Core & IIS Server : session cookie not set in production

Tags: asp.net-core

I am working on an ASP.NET Core web application. My dotnet version is 3.1.401 and I am with Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.7.2. I am using a session cookie that was working well with IIS Express.

I deployed the app on IIS Server v 10.0.19041.507. My authentication cookie (without ASP.NET Core Identity) is working fine but on the contrary the session cookie is not set.

Here is what I have in startup.cs

```
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.Name = ".FjDRegisterLLAT.Session";
                //options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(900);              
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
```

Let me precise that I removed the line : "app.UseCookiePolicy()" from startup.cs

In IIS, there is an option for the session state, but I really don't know how to configure this. Perhaps I should not even configure it as my authentication cookie is working and I didn't not change anything to it.

I still tried using the name of my cookie (see in statup.cs above) in place of the default one, but it does not change anything :

[image]

Here is a controller where I'am using the session cookie to retrieve data. I thought that when I would make a request to that controller, a value would be set along with the creation of the cookie like in development mode, but no !

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(bool isCheckingOut)
        {
            User user = GetUser();
            user.isCheckinOut = isCheckingOut;
            HttpContext.Session.SetComplexData("user", user);
            return RedirectToAction("SetStatus");
        }
```

*UPDATED_1*

In development mode, my cookie is set with the name and options as set in Startup.cs.
[image]

*UPDATED_2*

Apparently it has nothing to do with the application settings nor the IIS Server configuration. The session cookie is set properly by Edge and FireFox. It turns out that chrome does not want it.

Comment: Is production behind https?

Comment: yes it is behind https

Comment: which value would be set along and can you show us the cookie in development mode?

Comment: I put a printscreen in the question under "UPDATED"..
The first value to be set  is a boolean field from a User object where I store session data..

Comment: Try removing `options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;`.

Comment: I thought about that but apparently it's for http and https : "this option causes the web browsers to return the cookie using the http (or https) protocol only".. Don't think it will change anything but I will try anyway

Comment: @mxmissile I just tried, didn't change anything... I have been told not relying on session state to keep temp data.. I used it because I followed a tutorial..
next time I will follow that advice but here I don't want to change everything in my code.. there must be a way to create that cookie somehow..

Comment: @mxmissile the cookie is set properly by edge and firefox..it's all about chrome apparently..

Comment: Hi @Francois, did you find any solution for this? I am having the same problem

Comment: @doganilker Hi, unfortunately not.. I had to stop that project when covid all started.. Anyways, as far as I remember I got advised not to store session data within cookies but to persist them in DB and erase them when the user session is over.. sorry I cannot help any further

Comment: hi @Francois, thanks anyway:) I found my problem and want to write here, too. It may help someone. The problem was that my test environment was not had ssl certificate. but in startup.cs file, I wrote like "config.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always; ". this was my problem. I changed my code as described from that link [link]https://mariusschulz.com/blog/securing-authentication-cookies-in-asp-net-core

Comment: @doganilker I am glad you found a solution ;-)